# How to avoid duplicate input and empty input?

Tags: php, sql

This would be a piece of my code.

```
$name = $_POST['UserNames'];
$pw = sha1($_POST['Passwords']);
$mail = $_POST['Emails'];
$pc = $_POST['Postcodes'];
$status = "0";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO userinfo 
               (Username,Password,Email,Postcode,status,valid) 
               VALUES 
               ('$name','$pw','$mail','$pc','$status','$validate')
");
```

How do i make sure every input will not be null and the Email will never repeat.

Comment: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) ?

Comment: [array_filter](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for `$_POST` and [array_unique](http://pk1.php.net/array_unique) for `$_POST['Emails']` (If array)

Comment: Set a `UNIQUE` index on the column in the database and write code that validates the input before you insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO userinfo (Username,Password,Email,Postcode,status,valid) VALUES ('$name','$pw','$mail','$pc','$status','$validate')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status='0'");
```

For more details refer, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

use the `empty` function for the post fields to check if it contains something.

for the email, you must use a UNIQUE clause in your database for this field

Answer (score 0):

About the email: set up the column of Email in userinfo table to be unique, and on [insert just do on duplicate ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

About the fields, well in the way you are working just do isset($_POST['XXX']) && !empty($_POST['XXX']). A better way would be working with some input validation class, [like this one](http://laravel.com/docs/validation).

Answer (score 0):

For empty input you can do the following :

```
$name = (isset($_POST['UserNames']) && !empty($_POST['UserNames'])) ? $_POST['UserNames'] : FALSE;
```

For duplicate email check you need to do a SELECT query before executing the INSERT statement.

Answer (score -1):

First check values before mysql query:

```
$valid = true;
foreach($_POST AS $key=>$value)
{
   if($value == null){
       echo "Please provide ".$key;
       $valid = false;
   }
}
if($valid == true)
{
    // check if email is in DB
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM user info WHERE Email = '".addslashes($_POST['email'])."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
       echo "Email is already registered in our DB";
    }
    else
    {
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO userinfo (Username,Password,Email,Postcode,status,valid) VALUES ('$name','$pw','$mail','$pc','$status','$validate')");
    }
}
```

Comment: The query of select email is wrong way. The right way would be set Email column to unique.